# How to read csv file using CSV Data Set Config at once in Jmeter (instead of line by line)

Tags: csv, jmeter

I need to get whole text from csv file using CSV Data Set Config at once.

Comment: You just need to read all file to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, if you want to load the whole file into certain place in the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) or into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you can use [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) and provide the relative or full path to the CSV file like:

```
${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file.csv,,)}
```

if you want to save the file into the variable just provide the variable name as the last parameter:

```
${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file.csv,,foo)}
```

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to learn more about JMeter Functions concept